# How to add options to function arguments in R? That is when user hits tab they see all the possible values the argument can take

Tags: r, rstudio

Lets say I have a function with arguments x.

```
func<-function(x){
    if(x=='a'){.......}
    else if (x=='b'){........}
    else if (x=='c'){.........}
}
```

....... represents some code that I wish to execute.

Whenever I call the function from the console, hitting TAB lets me see the arguments the function takes, how do I also display the possible values of the argument so that the user can choose one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a package and add documentation to your functions. E.g., you can run `devtools::create("~/mypackage")` (change `~/mypackage` if you want). Then create a file at `~/mypackage/R` called `myfunc.R`. In this file set the following

```
#' @title What does this function do?
#' @param x if \code{a} then 1, if \code{b} then 2, if \code{c} then 3.
#' @param ... may have an effect in the future.
#' @export
myfunc <- function(x, ...){
  if(x=='a'){
    1
  }
  else if (x=='b'){
    2
  }
  else if (x=='c'){
    3
  } else
    stop(sQuote(x), " not implemented")
}
```

Then run `setwd("~/mypackage")`, `devtools::document()`, and `devtools::install()`. After that you can call `library(mypackage)` after which you can see the following in Rstudio

[image]

The above uses [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) and a R package which might be more then you ask for. Though, it

> ... display the possible values of the argument so that the user can choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the console in RStudio.  My understanding is that this is not currently a feature of RStudio. Maybe someone has developed an [RStudio Addin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/addinslist/README.html) that will do that for you though.